# how to mask recipients addresses , action mailer 4 with bcc: or other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailing

I am using action mailer with an array of emails. Emails are sending out successfully but in the received email, everyone can see the other recipients. I want to hide them from each other.

There are many posts about this and I've tried many things without success. Would be great if someone can spot what I'm doing wrong. I'm using rails 4.1.7. with delayed_job and devise. I am sure this must be something easy i have missed. Thanks in advance for any help.

My mailer is :

```
def send_email(mymodel)
  @mymodel = mymodel
  emails = @mymodel.followers.collect(&:email) 
  @url  = 'http://example.com/'
  mail(:to => emails, :bcc => ["noreply@example.com"], subject:"myemailsubject")  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mail(to: emails, bcc: ["noreply@example.com"], subject: "myemailsubject")
```

You could exchange the `bcc` value with the `to` value.

```
mail(to: ["noreply@example.com"], bcc: emails, subject: "myemailsubject")
```

That should send out only 1 email, yet achieve what you want. However the email recipients might be slightly confused if they read the `to` field and don't find their own email address.

You could try the following but obviously it'll send out multiple emails:

```
emails.each do |email|
  mail(to: email, bcc: ["noreply@example.com"], subject: "myemailsubject")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but that didn't help. with the first two options gives me many errors with "," and ")" . The loop sends many emails, with html and text mixed up and in all the emails you can see all recipients.

Comment: Ensure that the values you're passing to the mail method are in the right format.

Comment: You are right. It does send the emails. I probably had a typo... Though the recipients emails are still visible.

Comment: Umm... how can the recipients' emails be visible when they're in the BCC field?

Comment: my bad, i definitely had a typo. The second option worked! it sent all emails with the noreply... as recipients. Thank you so much for your help!